# How do I extract specific text from a HTML document in bash?

Tags: html, bash

I am trying to extract the text that is displayed just below the player from http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/series/m184177/match-clips/greater-things-lie-ahead-dravid/2002003068.

The text that I wish to extract is "Greater Things Lie Ahead: Dravid".

I tried using `curl` but I could not find them in the output that `curl` gave me. How do I do this?

Edit :- Analysing the page-source, the text I wish to extract lies in the {{pageTitle}} in < meta property="og:title" content="{{pageTitle}}">. Is there any way I can extract the value of {{pageTitle}} ?

Comment: It seems like the website is loading it via an asynchronous request. You may try to find which one is the correct request and try to mimic it.

Comment: moved from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421960/how-do-i-extract-specific-text-from-a-html-document-in-bash?noredirect=1#comment759248_421960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try headless Chrome for more stable result. I can get 10 out of 10 runs successfully in a row.

Setup:
Install Chrome

> npm init --yes
>   npm install --save chrome-remote-interface
>   npm install --save chrome-launcher
>   
>   Then save the following code to foo.js, and run:
>
> node foo "http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/series/m184177/match-clips/greater-things-lie-ahead-dravid/2002003068"

```
URL=process.argv[2]
const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
const file = require('fs');

(async function() {
    async function launchChrome() {
        return await chromeLauncher.launch({
            chromeFlags: [
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--headless'
            ]
        });
    }
    const chrome = await launchChrome();
    const protocol = await CDP({
        port: chrome.port
    });

    const {
        DOM,
        Network,
        Page,
        Emulation,
        Runtime
    } = protocol;
    await Promise.all([Network.enable(), Page.enable(), Runtime.enable(), DOM.enable()]);
    await Network.setUserAgentOverride({ userAgent });

    //uncomment the following line for network traffic checking
    //await Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {console.log(params.request.url);});

    await Page.navigate({
        url: URL
    });

    Page.loadEventFired(async() => {
        const js = "document.querySelector('.title-holder h1').textContent";
        const result = await Runtime.evaluate({ expression: js });

        console.log(result.result.value);

        protocol.close();
        chrome.kill();
    });

})();
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. But it is currently taking more than 3 minutes to run. Where do I need to edit the `foo.js` file if I have to do it for multiple URLs ?

Comment: It takes me 7 seconds only, every time. I added a line for you to check the network traffic. You can also remove the '--headless' parameter to see how the browser is working. If you want to pass in the URL as parameter, replace the URL with process.argv[2]. (i.e. 0 -> node, 1-> foo.js)

Comment: Yes. It is working now. If I am to pass undefined number of command line arguments, where should I begin my loop? I think the loop should begin before this line `await Page.navigate({ `
      and end right before  `protocol.close();  `
'. Am I correct here ?

Comment: I would loop the nodejs with shell script, to keep things simple. You can even make them parallel and limit the number of concurrent processes.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a ton. I have checked the script on windows. Once I have checked it on my Linux machine, I shall mark the answer.

Comment: Yes, it did the trick. Thanks a ton @uso.

Answer (score 1):

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getText() {
    return $('.title-holder').find('h1').text();
}

casper.options.waitTimeout = 60000;
casper.waitForSelector('.title-holder h1');
casper.start('http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/series/m184177/match-clips/greater-things-lie-ahead-dravid/2002003068');

casper.then(function () {
    console.log(this.evaluate(getText));
});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I tried this on Windows. It is taking three tries to get the correct output. First the output is nothing, then null and finally the text that I require.

Comment: @Abascus: I suppose the page limits the number of requests in a timeframe.

Comment: edit: I added 60 seconds timeout and make it wait for the target text. But still it fails a lot. You may test the result code $? and retry in bash shell. Or you may refer to my another answer using headless chrome for stable result.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of [uso's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48626159/3776858) without casper.

```
var url = 'http://www.hotstar.com/sports/cricket/series/m184177/match-clips/greater-things-lie-ahead-dravid/2002003068'
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(url, function(status) {
  var string = page.evaluate(function() {
    return $('.title-holder').find('h1').text();
  });
  console.log(string);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Usage: `phantomjs request.js`

Output:

```
Greater Things Lie Ahead: Dravid
```